# How to use counters with variables, error: %%, Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

In a loop I want to use a counter to use different variables.
The problem is that both use the % symbol: %VAR%

Showing where I get the error %%, Simplified:

```
textGH1 = Peter
textGH2 = rocks.

i = 1
Loop, 2
{
SendInput {Enter}
Sleep 50
SendInput, %textGH%i%%
Sleep 50
SendInput {Enter}
i++
}
```

Error: Empty variable reference %%

What I tried:
I have looked up arrays for autohotkey, but I only found
pseudo-arrays using the %COUNTER% as a workaround, similiar to how I
did it. Second, I have assigned a variable in the loop to your current variable:

```
text := textGH%i%
```

However this doesn't call the variable, as expected (needed %textGH%i%% again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying? Swap variables when the counter changes. Easiest way to do this is with an Array.

Here's a solution for you play with:

> Define Array. Array's Index values automatically, so Peter is at Index 1 Rocks is at Index 2.

```
MyArray := ["Peter", "Rocks"]
```

> Loop amount of times as there are Values in your Array.

```
Loop, % MyArray.MaxIndex() {  

SendInput {Enter}   
Sleep 50
```

> Send your Array at [Index] A_Index is a built in counter for Loops.

```
SendInput % MyArray[A_Index]   

Sleep 50    
SendInput {Enter} 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this, I get an error when initialising the Array: _"The following variable name contains an illegal character: "["Peter""_ I have double checked the copy paste.

Comment: You are probably using the old version of AutoHotkey which is no longer being updated. Download the latest version from ahkscript.org.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SendInput, %textGH%%i%
```

Comment: I have tried this, doesn't work, output is the counter itself "1" "2"